# The dataset 'DataSet1' refers to the data source "", which does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having this error "The dataset 'DataSet1' refers to the data source "", which does not exist." I'm making a report.rdlc, and I had to use some Tables which required DataSets... but I have to fill the field manualy. And now that I want to start my application that error shows up. What should I do?

Comment: Show the relevant code lines

Comment: I do not understand your question. Have you added a datasource to your table? What do you mean by "I have to fill the field manually"?

Comment: i dont have code lines. just i need to PRINT my report, i dont need any datatable.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was testing some things and added a table and then removed it. By doing that it automatically added a dataset named DataSet1. Adding another one and deleting it, created Dataset2,...

You can't see it but it's in your report.

I fixed it by right clicking the de report rdlc file and selecting open with and then selecting "automatic editor selector(XML)".

It opens the report in xml and at the top you see  with your Dataset1 in it. Just delete the tag  with everything in it and voila. Problem fixed:-)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

First open your rdlc report. Remove dataset1. Open Report Data (From Menu > View > Report Data) in visual studio. Now add data source with dataset. You can bind data in report using dataset. You can not use dataset added directly in folder. You have to add it from Report Data.